# dijit.byId on DOJO 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, dojo

[I'm following from the livedocs](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/byId) and try to use `registry.byId` (`dijit/registry` has required)

but the result is `undefined` I'm confused how is it wrong.

[Here is my code @jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YApwK/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle and it seems to work :)
[jsFiddle updated and working](http://jsfiddle.net/YApwK/2/)
You forgot to add a dojo.ready

Comment: Thank you, this dojo.ready business is somewhat obscure to me :)